# pytorch export to onnx - is there a mapping between the pytorch layer names and onnx layer names?

Tags: pytorch, export, onnx

I am exporting float pytorch model to onnx.
In addition I quantize the float pytorch model in native pytorch quantization.
My problem is that I need a map between observers names (which come from the pytorch model's layers names) and onnx layers names.
I haven't found a way yet to map between the two.
Anyone have a solution?
Thanks
chenru

Comment: any update ? im also struggle